# If a relation is neither Symmetric nor Anti-Symmetric, can it still be an order of some kind?

Tags: relations, order-theory

Say I have a relation that is Irreflexive and Transitive, but neither Symmetric nor Anti-Symmetric, can it still be a strict partial and / or strict total ordering? I realise this is an edge case, I appreciate any comments :)

Comment: Well, if we take a non-strict order and remove all relations $x\leqslant x$, we get a strict order. If we remove some of those and leave some others, we end up with your case.

Comment: Thank you very much! I couldn't get a definitive answer through googling. Much appreciated!

Comment: If it's irreflexive and transitive then it has to be antisymmetric.

Comment: It's also worth learning about partial orders, for which some $x\ne y$ satisfy neither $x\lt y$ nor $y\lt x$.